# Center div over canvas element

Tags: css, html5-canvas

Using [`react-globe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-globe), I'm trying to center a div with a message over the canvas element that can also be removed once a user interacts with the globe. I have the div in the page, but can't get it centered over the canvas element.

Current state: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-globe-interactive-forked-cdmkd?file=/public/style.css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the absolute position centring technique by adding:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%);
```

[image: Edit [react-globe] interactive (forked)]

Note that this currently centers relative to root, to center is relative to the `"globe-wrapper"` add `position: relative` to it.

Comment: I realized that I hadn't updated my original link to set the globe to `width: 70vw` as I have it in my project. When I adjust to that the overlay is off. I also can't get the overlay to align over the canvas in general.

Comment: @Matt the element needs to be inside a parent with `70vw` to be positioned at the center of `70vw`. Apply the `70vw`  and `position: relative` higher up or move the element into the `<div>` with `70vw`